# MSG_READALL is to recv() as ?? is to send()

Tags: sockets, unix, tcp

From the `recv(2)` man page:

> `MSG_WAITALL`
>
> This flag requests that the operation block until the full request is satisfied. However, the call may still return less data than requested if a signal is caught, an error or disconnect occurs, or the next data to be received is of a different type than that returned.

It doesn't look like there's an equivalent flag for `send(2)`, which strikes me as strange.  Maybe `send()`s are guaranteed to always accept the whole buffer, but I don't see that written anywhere (and anyway, that seems unlikely to me).

Is there a way to tell `send()` to wait until it's sent the whole buffer before returning, equivalently to `recv()`'s `MSG_WAITALL`?

Edit: I understand that send() just copies data into a buffer in the operating system and that I can't force send() to put data onto the wire.  My question is: Can I force send() to block until all the data I gave it has been copied into the OS's buffer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[You can't](http://www.unixguide.net/network/socketfaq/2.11.shtml). `send` just offloads the buffer to the kernel, then returns.

To quote from the [Unix standard](http://www.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/009695399/functions/send.html):

> The `send()` function shall initiate transmission of a message from the specified socket to its peer (...)
>   Successful completion of a call to send() does not guarantee delivery of the message.

Note the word "initiate". It doesn't actually send anything, rather tells the OS to send the message when it's ready for it (when its buffers are full or after some time has passed).

Comment: `TCP_NODELAY` does not disable buffering - it turns off Nagle algorithm that minimizes small packets.

Comment: By combining them into larger packets; isn't that a form of buffering? `tcp(7)` says: "When not set, data is buffered".

Comment: Data is still buffered. The Nagle makes TCP not wait for an `ACK` to piggyback on small data packets, and makes no difference on large packets.

Comment: I don't think the page you linked to answers my question.

I understand that I can't force the data onto the wire.  The question is just about the API: Can I force send() to wait until all the data has been placed into the OS's buffer before returning?

Comment: @Justin L., that's because you seem to search for something that doesn't exist. Either that, or I didn't understand your question.

Comment: "that's because you seem to search for something that doesn't exist"

That's fair.  :)

Answer (score 0):

[`send(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/send.2.html) for TCP does not actually "send" anything on the wire, but places your bytes into the socket send buffer. It tells you how many bytes it was able to copy there in the return value.

Make the send buffer bigger (see [`setsockopt(2)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man2/setsockopt.2.html) and [`tcp(7)`](http://www.kernel.org/doc/man-pages/online/pages/man7/tcp.7.html)), pay attention to the syscall return value. In any case, TCP is a stream. You need to manage application-level protocol yourself.